# Show the buy button and process the payment on facebook messenger with Bot Framework

Tags: facebook, botframework

How can I process the payment process using the bot framework ?  Is there any type of cards that I can send to show the buy button .

I know we can use JObject to send a direct json text , but how can we have it just like the other features of the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Channel's specific features (such as the Buy button from Facebook) are supported through the [ChannelData](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/channels.html) (C#) / [sourceEvent](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/calling-reference/interfaces/_botbuilder_d_.iconversation.html#sourceevent) (Node) fields. So you need to send the specific info through it so Facebook can understand it and react accordingly.

[Here](http://southworks.com/blog/2016/09/15/sending-facebooks-quick-replies-using-microsoft-bot-framework/) is a similar example, but instead of using the Buy button I'm sending Facebook's Quick Replies.

You can also find more details about how to use new Facebook's features with BotFramework in this [blog post](https://blog.botframework.com/2016/09/15/facebook-messenger-updates/).