# MS Bot Framework Response to Facebook Payment Buy Request

Tags: facebook, botframework, facebook-payments

When you show a buy button on Facebook the callback to your bot is an "invoke". Details here [[Show the buy button and process the payment on facebook messenger with Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686386/show-the-buy-button-and-process-the-payment-on-facebook-messenger-with-bot-frame])

It is up to the bot to respond to FB with a 200 for success or something else for a failure. No matter what response I've sent Facebook processes the request as if it were successful.

v3.0 of the bot framework with the C# Connector SDK

I've attempted:

Standard reply:

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
Activity replyToConversation = activity.CreateReply();
replyToConversation.Recipient = activity.From;
replyToConversation.Type = "invoke";
connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivity(replyToConversation);
or
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
or
return Request.CreateErrorResponse(...);
or
return null;
```

I've also forced the Controller to respond with an error by throwing a new exception.

There was a suggestion to rely using channelData however channelData seems to only support attachment type replies and what is needed here is a direct reply to the Payment request.

How do I correctly respond to FB to indicate the payment was NOT successful?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1859 and https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2475

Comment: @stuartd thanks the second link is the issue I raised but got no response so expanding the audience. The first link is what I referenced. It seems to indicate a way to reply directly without answering the question of how to actually send the 200 or other status message directly.